# SignalR and mobile network connection

Tags: mobile, connection, signalr, 3g

I have a signalR chat app which works however when I switch my connection on my mobile device from wifi to mobile/3G all functionality is stopped. The same error I receive is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined.

I have done a lot of investigating and cannot find a solution. My hub on my asp.net and desktop app connects to my hub server on a http://192.168.x.x:8080/signalr url.

I am aware that the hub is not connecting hence the error above...How do I resolve this issue?

Please if I can get some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Because this is essentially on your local network 192.168.x.x. You need dynamic DNS or something similar and a host name for this to work with anything outside your local network such as mobile or another PC.

Comment: thanks Steve...my problem was much simpler than anticipated...made the change and everything is working great.